# fastest way to redirect to static (possibly cached) page from a fastcgi application running on nginx?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

nginx is handling all static page requests, but from within my fastcgi application I may want to send certain requests to a static page. is there something that I can printf and some setting in nginx I can add to make it serve the page? or should I just use the fastcgi app to read the disc and serve it?

nginx 1.0.8
I'm using c++ for the fastcgi if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application can set an [X-Accel-Redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) response header to tell nginx to internally redirect to the specified location and serve a file.